# MKMapView should always head towards the moving direction

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa, mkmapview, mapkit

I want to accomplish the following:

When user is moving on the `MKMapView`, the `MapView` should always head to the moving direction of the user.
As user will change his direction the map view should rotate itself and again heads to the moving direction of user.

I have used `MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading`, but it is working with compass. I dont want to use compass here as it is not fulfilling what i want to implement.

I found Waze app doing exactly the same i want to do. Anyone have an idea or solutions to implement this behaviour.
Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Just keep the user's location centered in the map view, and compute a heading based on the last two known positions. Use that heading to orient the map.

Comment: Can you guide me on how i can implement it. Any reference or help would be highly appreciated. @Caleb